# Ternary statements in styled components React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am having trouble, understanding how styled components handles props and using a ternary statement to control CSS elements.  Here is the code that I have already tried and don't understand why it doesn't work.  I am trying to acheive a similar effect to this

```
<div id={props.data === "blueborder" ? "blueContainer" : "redContainer"}>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Container></Container>

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: ${props => props.data === "blueborder" ? "solid blue" : "solid red"};
`;
```

Comment: Your shared code works perfectly to change color of div. But `id={props.data === "blueborder" ? "blueContainer" : "redContainer"} ` assign the dynamic id to div, which is not same.

Comment: for border style try this one, style = { props.data === "blueborder" ? { border:'solid blue'} : {border : 'solid red'} }

Answer (score 0):

This code works you just omit to pass props data to your Container: 
   `<Container data="blueborder"/>`
see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-firefly-byho6?file=/src/App.js:450-484)